# Django queryset filter model where related objects have ALL a field value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   # fields

class PhotoTags(models.Model):
   photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name="tags")
   tag_name = models.Charfield()
   is_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get photos where tags are *all* with is_disabled = True.

Is it possible to achieve it with a query, or do I have to loop photos and for each one check all tags?

**EDIT**

I tried with

```
Photos.objects.filter(tags__is_disabled=True)
```

but it returns photos with at least one tag that is disabled

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried that's not working?  Please see the guidance on creating a [Minimal, Complete verifiable example question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OP - Given your comment on correcting Jay Daves now deleted answer. What exactly are you struggling with here?

Comment: hey, I'm not deleted the Jay Daves answer, I'm composing my answer but he deleted himself his message in the meanwhile

Answer (score -2):

Yo can use `Photo.objects.filter(tags__is_disabled=True)`

Comment: 1) it should be .filter(tags__is_disabled=True)
2) filter() returns photos with at least one tag that is disabled
3) first() is for what?

Comment: Try this @user1518217